# Building spring boot reactive API with http2

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, reactive

I am newbie to reactive programming. I want to convert a REST API (monolithic architecture) to Reactive micro service using http2 version.

API performs following tasks:

1. Authorization
2. Validation
3. Calling multiple external Rest API's
4. Some DB operations

Above all tasks are synchronous. Can you help me to understand in high level what all changes would be required to convert it to reactive API? Which framework goes best with Spring boot for building reactive API?
When should I go for event sourcing here?